Outdoor-rated fastener for concrete epoxy anchor
In order to mount some brackets to hold unistruts channels I need to insert some fasteners into a concrete slab I poured a couple of years ago (outdoors, exposed to rain etc). I would like to drill and then use designated epoxy adhesive. So far so good.
Where it gets confusing for me is - I obviously need to get the threaded studs that will stick out of the concrete. As far as I know, it is not common to find such studs for sale. Should I assume people buy threaded rods and cut them to length? It is not a difficult process but it's kind of laborious, and most importantly the area that is cut will not have a coating to protect the fastener from corrosion.
That pretty much means I will have to use stainless steel rod, cut it to length etc - are there better solutions?

How much thread do you need exposed?  I have seen expansion anchors as long as 7 inches.

If you got short sections of threaded rod, and cut them in the middle, you’d still have two galvanized ends.

Have you considered expansion bolts? Upside: Some of them can be removed, on a good day, by tapping the stud down with a hammer and then gently pulling the anchor out of the hole. Downside: In a freezing environment they may allow water to get into the holes and freeze. There are also studs that can be set with a powder-actuated tool, Quick, if a bit noisy. (Use your favorite search engine to look for ramset studs.)

I'd rather stay with epoxy anchors - this is on a slab floor so I like to prevent water ingress in the hole that can corrode the fastener inside. I am just surprised that, along with epoxy-based products, there are no dedicated fasteners but one needs to buy and cut rod. Yeah I like the trick of cutting one in half to preserve a galvanized end

Nifty product, but probably not DIY: adhesive bonded undercut anchor. The installation video shows that it combines undercut mechanical retention with adhesive fill in a rather tidy manner.

A few passes with an angle grinder on a stainless rod is laborious?  I mean, I guess pre-threading some nuts on the rod before cutting is a little extra work, but...
